# Invoking .jar file doesn't work in php shell_exec linux but it works in cmd and windows

Tags: java, php, linux, shell, imagej

I am working on a script that calls the Imagej java app to process an image uploaded by a PHP web page.
The problem occurs when the PHP shell_exec command calls the app.
The structure was tested in windows and worked correctly.
However, when trying to implement in linux, shell_exec halts the php script and stays loading forever. In the same shell_exec "java -version" worked, but calling the jar did not work.
the shell_exec command is:

```
java -Xmx512m -Dplugins.dir="/var/www/ImageJ/" -jar "/var/www/ImageJ/ij.jar" -batch "/var/www/ImageJ/macros/[macrofile]" [imagefile.jpeg]
```

However when I try to run in php from console, it runs.

```
php > shell_exec("java -Xmx512m -Dplugins.dir=\"/var/www/ImageJ/\" -jar \"/var/www/ImageJ/ij.jar\" -batch \"/var/www/ImageJ/macros/melaTest.ijm\" F15274739305711.jpeg");
```

Could it be a problem with php.ini or user?

Comment: tested on linux command prompt? is 'java' in the local path?

Comment: php user user has read access\write access to those files\directories?

Comment: The imagej folder is in /var/www/ (apache2), the command above worked fine when put in LXTerminal. Java is in /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-i386/bin.

Comment: However when I try to run in php from console, it runs.

php > shell_exec("java -Xmx512m -Dplugins.dir=\"/var/www/ImageJ/\" -jar \"/var/www/ImageJ/ij.jar\" -batch \"/var/www/ImageJ/macros/melaTest.ijm\" F15274739305711.jpeg");

Could it be a problem with php.ini or user?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was fixed.
The issue was related to GUI nature of ImageJ, so the app expected a virtual screen to run from shell_exec.
To solve the problem it was installed Xvfb (sudo apt install xvfb) and the command inside php shell_exec was called from the command "xvfb-run" to execute in a virtual server.

```
 xvfb-run -a -s "-screen 0 1024x768x24" java -Xmx512m -Dplugins.dir="/var/www/ImageJ/" -jar "/var/www/ImageJ/ij.jar" -batch "/var/www/ImageJ/macros/[macro...] [arg]
```